# when adding a new item the functionality of the previous item changes

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const addBtn = document.querySelector(".add");
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal__container");
const library = document.querySelector(".library__container");
const submitBook = document.querySelector(".add__book");
const deleteBtn = document.querySelector(".fas fa-trash-alt");
//Modal inputs
const modalTitle = document.querySelector("#title");
const modalAuthor = document.querySelector("#author");
const modalPages = document.querySelector("#pages");
const isRead = document.querySelector("#read-status");

//Toggle Modal
const hideModal = () => {
    modal.style.display = "none";
 };
 const showModal = () => {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    const cancel = document.querySelector(".cancel");
    cancel.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        hideModal();
    });
 };
 addBtn.addEventListener("click", showModal);

let myLibrary = [];
let index = 0;

function Book(title, author, pages, read) {
    this.title = title,
    this.author = author,
    this.pages = pages,
    this.read = read
}


submitBook.addEventListener("click", addBookToLibrary);

function addBookToLibrary(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   let bookTitle = modalTitle.value;
   let bookAuthor = modalAuthor.value;
   let bookPages = modalPages.value;
   let bookStatus = isRead.checked;

   //Display error message if inputs are empty
   if (bookTitle === "" || bookAuthor === "" || bookPages === "") {
       const errorMessage = document.querySelector(".error__message--container");
       hideModal();
       errorMessage.style.display = "block";
       const errorBtn = document.querySelector(".error-btn");
       errorBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
           errorMessage.style.display = "none";
           showModal();
       })
   } else {
    let book = new Book(bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookPages, bookStatus);
    myLibrary.push(book);
    
    hideModal();
    render();
   }

}

function render() {
    library.innerHTML = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
        library.innerHTML += 
        '<div class="book__container">' +
        '<div class="book">' +
            '<div class="title__content">' +
                '<span class="main">Title : </span><span class="book__title">' +` ${myLibrary[i].title}`+'</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="author__content">' +
                '<span class="main">Author : </span><span class="book__author">'+` ${myLibrary[i].author}`+'</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="pages__content">' +
                '<span class="main">Pages : </span><span class="book__pages">'+` ${myLibrary[i].pages}`+'</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="book__read-elements">' +
                '<span class="book__read">I read it</span>' +
                '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>' +
                '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-times"></i>' +
                '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>'
    readStatus(myLibrary[i].checked)
    }
    
    modalTitle.value = "";
    modalAuthor.value = "";
    modalPages.value = "";
    isRead.checked = false;
}

function readStatus(bookStatus) {
        const bookStatusContainer = document.querySelector(".book__read");
    if (bookStatus) {
        bookStatusContainer.classList.add("yes");
        bookStatusContainer.textContent = "I read it";
        bookStatusContainer.style.color = "rgb(110, 176, 120)";
    } else {
        bookStatusContainer.classList.add("no");
        bookStatusContainer.textContent = "I have not read it";
        bookStatusContainer.style.color = "rgb(194, 89, 89)";
    }
      
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;600&display=swap');
:root {
    --light-gray: #dededef3;
    --title-color: #333756;
    --main-color: #c6c6c6f3;

}
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-color: var(--light-gray);
}
header {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 4rem;
    color: var(--title-color);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}
button {
    margin: 1rem;
    padding: 0.8rem 2rem;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: white;
    color: #333756;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.6s all ease;
}
:focus {
    /*outline: 1px solid white;*/
}

button:hover {
    background: var(--title-color);
    color: white;
}
.add__book:hover,
.cancel:hover {
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: var(--title-color)
}
.all,
.books__read,
.books__not-read {
    border-radius: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    background: var(--light-gray);
    border-bottom: 4px solid var(--title-color)
}
.library__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.book__container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 2rem 2rem;
}
.modal__container {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding-top: 0px;
}
.book,
.modal {
    padding: 2rem 2rem;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #333756;
    line-height: 3rem;
}
.modal {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 8rem;
}
.modal__content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
label {
    color: white;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}
input {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.book__read-elements {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.main,
i {
    color: white;
    pointer-events: none;
    margin: 0.5rem;
}
.book__title,
.book__author,
.book__pages,
.book__read {
    color: var(--main-color)
}
.error__message--container {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.error__message--modal {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10rem;
    width:40%;
}
.error {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    color: rgb(101, 3, 3);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: rgb(189, 96, 96);
    padding: 3rem 5rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.error-btn {
    color: rgb(101, 3, 3);
    font-weight: bold;
}
.error-btn:hover {
    color: white;
    background: rgb(101, 3, 3);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-2XFplPlrFClt0bIdPgpz8H7ojnk10H69xRqd9+uTShA=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Library</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>My Library</h1>
        <button class="add">Add New Book</button>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="all">View All</button>
            <button class="books__read">Read</button>
            <button class="books__not-read">Not Read</button>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="error__message--container">
        <div class="error__message--modal">
            <div class="error">
                <p>Complete the form!</p>
                <button class ="error-btn">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Modal-->
    <form class="modal__container">
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal__content">
                <label for="">Title:</label>
                <input type="text" id="title"> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal__content">
                <label for="">Author:</label>
                <input type="text" id="author">
            </div>
            <div class="modal__content">
                <label for="">Pages:</label>
                <input type="number" id="pages">
            </div>
            <div>
            <label for="read-status">Check the box if you've read this book</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="read-status" value ="check">
            </div>
            
            <button class="add__book">Add</button>
            <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <!--End of Modal-->
    <div class="library__container"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to OOP and I'm struggling.
I'm building a library where you can add a book with the title, author nr of pages and if you've read it or not. When I add the first book if I check the box it displays that to book is not read(which is false). When I add a new book the read functionality is not applied to that book at all. I have no idea how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

In this function you are checking the status if `isRead` which is incorrect.

Do this

1. Call the readStatus function inside the for loop
2. Pass the current parameter `readStatus(myLibrary[i].checked)`
3. Modify readStatus as shown below

```
function readStatus(status) {
  const bookReadStatus = document.querySelector(".book__read");
  if (status) {
    bookReadStatus.classList.add("yes");
    bookReadStatus.textContent = "I read it";
    bookReadStatus.style.color = "rgb(110, 176, 120)";
  } else {
    bookReadStatus.classList.add("no");
    bookReadStatus.textContent = "I have not read it";
    bookReadStatus.style.color = "rgb(194, 89, 89)";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it doesn't change the status of the first book added, but the books added after don't show the read status... I'll try to figure it out